# Can a makefile build a several targets using one line?

Tags: c, makefile

I have a makefile which lists a number of static libraries to build, each in it's own subfolder. I've defined them like this in the top-level makefile:

```
LIBS= \
lib1 \
lib2 \
etc...
```

I'm trying to get the makefile to CD into each subfolder using these names (e.g. lib/lib1, lib/lib2) and build the per-library makefiles it finds. Can I do this with a single target, rather than a separate target for each library?

Something like this:

```
libs : $(LIBS)

$(LIBS) :
    if [ -f /lib/${@}/makefile ]; then cd /lib/${@}; make; fi
```

I'm not sure that $@ is the correct variable here, as only the first library is built.

Many thanks!

Comment: are you forced to use handcrafted makefiles? if not, look at automated build systems, e.g. autotools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The makefile snippet you provide is (mostly) correct and should work as you expect.  If your real makefile is not working as expected, that means there's something different between it and the example you've provided here.  In that case there's no way we can help.  Please cut and paste an actual failing example, plus the command you invoked and the output you got from make.

One note, you should *never* use the static `make` command when invoking sub-makes.  *Always* use the `$(MAKE)` variable.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that only the first library in $LIBS is built.

Comment: Yes, so you clearly stated in your original question.  That is not helpful since the makefile you've provided will definitely build all the libraries.  So if only the first library is built, then there is some difference between the description of your environment you've given here, and the ACTUAL environment you're using when you see the error.  We can't help you solve the problem in this situation.  Here's a question: if you run `make libs` does it build them all?  Are you sure you've put `libs` as the _FIRST_ target in your real makefile, as you show it in your question above?

Comment: Thanks - it was in the wrong order. Please excuse the mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

Use of 'foreach' function will simplify the rule. I think following makefile will work fine (Not tested):

```
LIBS := lib1 lib2 lib3


libs: 
     -@$(foreach l, $(LIBS), make -C /lib/$(l))
```